# antlr4 lexer predicate documentation

Tags: antlr4

Several questions on antlr4 have used lexer predicates which have not been mentioned in the book, eg [28730446](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730446) uses **ahead**(String), [42058127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058127) uses **getCharPositionInLine**(), [23465358](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465358) uses **_input.LA(1)**, etc. The **_input.LA(1)** is also used a few times in the book (eg on pages 212 and 228 of the 2014 edition) but there is no explanation on what it exactly does. Is there a list of available lexer predicates, and their documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not lexer predicates. Rather, they are ordinary methods on run-time objects: `Token#getCharPositionInLine()` and `CharStream#LA(int)`. The documentation is provided in the [source code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.java).

The Lexer class defines `_input` as

```
public CharStream _input;
```

Also, the `ahead()` method is custom defined in the `@lexer::members` block at the top of that particular grammar (and depends on the use of `CharStream#LA(int)`).

TDAR remains the best expositive documentation. The source code is internally well documented.